# Storing what page I am currently are when scrolling to the bottom JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I detect when I am at the bottom of the page.
I have a input hidden on the html, and when you scroll to the bottom, the input gets +1, but, when you get to the bottom, it adds alot of numbers.

How I add only +1 and it doesn't get alot of +1?

```
function finalPage() {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() -500) {
                loadMore();
            }
        });
    }

var num = $("#page").val();
num++;
$("#page").val(num);
```

Comment: welcome to stackOverflow, [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), please post a smallest reproducible example of your problem to make the question more clear

Comment: Why are the last three lines just sitting there and not inside a function? They don't look like you want them to happen when the page is loaded. Also, what's the point of the hidden input? Why not simply use a variable instead?

Comment: The three lines are inside loadMore() at the bottom sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function finalPage() {
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() -500) {
      loadMore();

      $("#page").val($("#page").val()+1);
    }
  });
}
```